# LinkedIn: Invalid redirect URI error

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have created a sample call for LinkedIn authorization as follows:

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://ws-100945:9080/ArtisWeb/index.html&state=9867998869&scope=r_basicprofile

but it is throwing an "Invalid redirect URI" error, I have double-checked the `redirect_uri`, it is correct one. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: 1. the `redirect_uri` value should be url-encoded 2. double-check the URL also wrt. "http" vs."https" and port number 3. make sure you use the right `client_id`

Comment: Hi, thanks for for quick response.I checked points 2,3,tehy are perfect.However, 1 is not much clear to me..how redirect_uri must be url-encoded..could you give me example for same?

Comment: i have encoded url and its working now.thnks:)

Comment: great, I've converted it in to an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 things to check:

1. the redirect_uri value should be url-encoded
2. double-check the URL also wrt. "http" vs."https" and port number
3. make sure you use the right client_id